# Servlet para adicionar Contatos no mySQL não funciona

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlet

Tenho um html enviando `request` para uma `servlet` que responde com erro porém quando mando rodar uma classe `testaAdicionaContato`.

tabela do mySQL 5:

```
create table contatos (
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
endereco VARCHAR(255),
dataNascimento DATE,
primary key (id)
);
```

classe TestaAdicionaContato:

```
package br.com.caelum.servlet;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class TestaAdicionaContato {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Contato contato = new Contato();
        contato.setNome("nome");
        contato.setEndereco("endereco");
        contato.setEmail("email");
        contato.setDataNascimento(Calendar.getInstance());

        ContatoDAO dao  = new ContatoDAO();
        dao.adiciona(contato);
    }

}
```

Servlet AdicionaContato chamada quando preencho o formulário em localhost:8080/agenda/adiciona-contato-html

```
package br.com.caelum.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/adicionaContato")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AdicionaContato extends HttpServlet {
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // busca o writer
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // buscando os parâmetros no request
        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
        String endereco = request.getParameter("endereco");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String dataEmTexto = request.getParameter("dataNascimento");
        Calendar dataNascimento = null;

        // fazendo a conversão da data
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dataEmTexto);
            dataNascimento = Calendar.getInstance();
            dataNascimento.setTime(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            out.println("Erro de conversão da data");
            return; // para a execução do método
        }

        // monta um objeto contato
        Contato contato = new Contato();
        contato.setNome(nome);
        contato.setEndereco(endereco);
        contato.setEmail(email);
        contato.setDataNascimento(dataNascimento);

        // salva o contato
        ContatoDAO dao = new ContatoDAO();
        dao.adiciona(contato);

        // imprime o nome do contato que foi adicionado
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("Contato " + contato.getNome() + " adicionado com sucesso");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException
>     br.com.caelum.servlet.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:13)
>     br.com.caelum.servlet.ContatoDAO.(ContatoDAO.java:24)
>     br.com.caelum.servlet.AdicionaContato.service(AdicionaContato.java:49)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) note The
>   full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.41 logs.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Sua exceção ocorre na ConnectionFactory.java, método getConnection. Muito provavelmente você não está utilizando um driver de conexao, ou está utilizando o mesmo incorretamente (sem incluir o jar no classpath).

Comment: Consegui resolver. Obrigado pela ajuda!